# bash script LAMP creation "yes"

Tags: linux, bash, lamp

I wrote this little bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash


apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install apache2
apt-get install php5
apt-get install mysql-server
apt-get install php5-mysql
service apache2 restart
apt-get update 
apt-get install python-software-properties
apt-get install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install php5
apt-get install vsftpd
apt-get install php5-curl
```

in order to create lamp and install php 5.6 on ubuntu 14.04

Everything works just fine, but I need to type "y" when prompted for and one time I need to hit enter (at this line:

`add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6`)

The script executes without typing "y" when running it with

```
yes | ./script.sh
```

but at the point I need to hit enter, it just gives me an output of numerous "y" and breaks. 
After running the script those files:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

are locked and I need to unlock them again, in order to install further stuff.

Is there a way to get this running properly? Without a lock of files and just doing what it is supposed to do...

Comment: Why are you executing `apt-get update` so many times? You should only have to do it up front and after adding the `ppa:ondref/php5-5.6` repo. Also, both `apt-get` and `add-apt-repository` have `-y` flags which assume that you want `yes` to everything. Additionally, you may want to set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` in the environment, which will take the default choice for any prompts that come up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change each `apt-get install` to  `apt-get -y install` and change `add-apt-repository` to `add-apt-repository -y` to assume yes for all questions.